# How to override page.html.twig in module for my custom page

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have a custom page defined in routing with it's `ControllerBase` class. I want to override the whole `page.html.twig` for this page.

If I use `hook_theme` and define there `'page__test' => [...]` it overrides page with my `page--test.html.twig`, but I don't have variables from `ControllerBase` class.

Answer (score 0):

To override the whole `page.html.twig` template for your custom page you can use the following approach:

1. In your theme or custom module, implement `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter` to suggest a custom template for your page:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function my_theme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Check if this is your custom page.
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'your.route_name') {
    // Suggest a custom template for the page.
    $suggestions[] = 'page__test';
  }
}
```

2. Create a custom template file `page--test.html.twig` in your theme or module's templates directory, in this file you can access variables from `ControllerBase` class:

```html
{# themes/custom/my_theme/templates/page--test.html.twig #}

<div class="layout-container">

  <header role="banner">
    {{ page.header }}
  </header>

  {{ page.primary_menu }}
  {{ page.secondary_menu }}

  {{ page.breadcrumb }}

  {{ page.highlighted }}

  {{ page.help }}

  <main role="main">
    <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>

    <div class="layout-content">
      {{ page.content }}
    </div>

    {% if page.sidebar_first %}
      <aside class="layout-sidebar-first" role="complementary">
        {{ page.sidebar_first }}
      </aside>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page.sidebar_second %}
      <aside class="layout-sidebar-second" role="complementary">
        {{ page.sidebar_second }}
      </aside>
    {% endif %}

  </main>

  {% if page.footer %}
    <footer role="contentinfo">
      {{ page.footer }}
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

</div>
```